# Going back when clicked the back button - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIViewCOntroller`, and my code is as follows.

```
TviewController *tviewController = [[TviewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tviewController animated:YES];
```

Now from `TviewController`  i go to another viewCOntroller;

```
XviewController *xviewController = [[XviewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:xviewController animated:YES];
```

in this `XviewController` there is a button, when i click that button i need to move **BACK** to the `TviewController` How do i do this programatically ?

note: I don't want to use `pushViewController` and push it further. I need to go back to the `TviewController` (as in clicking the back button twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is 3 possible ways.

1. use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` -> to go back root view controller (first view controller)
2. use `popViewControllerAnimated:` -> to go backward 1. it's exact same way as back button.
3. use `popToViewController:animated:` -> to go back to `UIViewController` you want (as long as it's stack at back).

point 1 & 2 is pretty easy to implement and other answers lead you to there.

for point 3, here it is:

```
@class TviewController.h;
@interface XviewController : UIViewController
{
//this is XviewController.h
//you may use `#import` other than use `@class` but on some reason you can't, if you use`#import XviewController.h` in your TviewController class.
}
```

---

```
//XviewController.m
#import TviewController.h
#import XviewController.h
@implementation

-(IBAction) backTviewController
{
   for ( UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers ) 
      if ( [viewController isMemberOfClass:[TviewController class]]{
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        break;
      } 
}
```

Comment: So if i am to use the 3rd method i should use `@class` instead of `import` ?

Comment: yes, safer. yo may use `@class` in .h, & add `#import` also in .m. or just use `#import` in .h . either one should work. hard to explain why, it's another question with another topic and answer :).

Comment: Thanks. you should accept one answer you find helpful. up your increase rate.

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You should spend some time reading the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) about view controllers...

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:BOOL)]
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)];

        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)];
```

are methods to go back in hierarchy